# ¿Cómo sacar el valor a partir de una clave de un objeto obtenido mediante get JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

mi problema es el siguiente. Yo a partir de un get llamo  a un controlador con php/laravel y obtengo mediante get un objeto con con dos estructuras dentro, una que se llama OldMessages y la otra se llama usersInfo . Recorro la información que me llega con un map para así obtener la información y mostrarla en la vista.
A partir de la "array" de usersInfo lo que hago con es crear una lista con calve:valor. Pero no se como obtener el valor a partir de una clave.
Esste es el objeto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que básicamente la lista de userinfo que creo que partir del objeto pues quiero acceder a los valores con la clase y no se como hacerlo.

Aqui el codigo:

```
$.getJSON("url-Web"+$("#toTalk").val(), (response)=>{
    $.each( response, function( key, val ) {
        usersInfo = response.userName
        console.log(usersInfo)
        response.old_messages.map((data)=>{
            // console.log(data.message)
            postWall.prepend("<div class=\"msg\" user-id=\""+data.from+"\" ><strong>"+ getName(usersInfo, data.from)+":</strong>"+data.message+"</div>");
        })
    });
    if(postWall.children().length == 0){
        postWall.prepend("<h1 style=\"color:red;\">No tienes ningun mensaje con esta persona</h1>")
    }
})
```

El método que uso:

```
function getName(object , okey){
    x = object.map((info)=>{
        if(info.id == okey){
            return info.name
        }
    })
    return x
}
```

Ahora el problema es que el map se ejecuta 3 veces...

Comment: Intentas recorrer un array `usersInfo`? Si es así, puedes hacer otro map de `usersInfo` tal y como haces con la respuesta, ya que es un array de objetos

Comment: @Zander Si pero lo que quiero hacer es a partir de una clave pues obtener su valor y meter un map dentro de otro, a parte de no se sabe muy bien pues es poco eficiente

Comment: si tienes una clave, al hacer el map, puedes comprobar dichas claves: mi clave es "5", pues dentro del map, hago un if (data.clave == "5") { ... } else { ... } Deduzco que eso lo quieres incluir en el `response.old_messages`, no?

Comment: @Zander Entonces debería hacer una función a parte que me devuelva el valor que yo busco?¿

Comment: Por favor, quita la segunda imagen y copia el código como texto. No se ve nada claro tal y como está, la imagen es demasiado pequeña. Además, no podemos copiar el texto a la respuesta para crear una solución al problema

Comment: @PabloLozano Ahí lo tienes

Comment: @MohaMBS no entendi lo que querias. ¿Quieres obtener el registro de `userName` a partir de un `id`? Porque por lo que veo un `for` basta para hacer todo eso

Comment: Aunque sigo sin entender porque recorrer 2 veces usando `each` y `map` para obtener esos valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando lo que creo que quieres realizar, esto debería funcionar (no lo he podido probar).

En el map de los `old_messages` comprobamos primero si existe el usuario (user.id, o como se llame la variable que tiene el id) y devuelve ese objeto, de lo contrario devuelve un false, y partiendo de ahí, si no es false, incluimos el prepend

```js
$.getJSON("url-Web"+$("#toTalk").val(), (response)=>{
    $.each( response, function( key, val ) {
        usersInfo = response.userName
        console.log(usersInfo)
        response.old_messages.map((data)=>{
            let user = isUserMatching(usersInfo, data.from)
            if (user) {
              // if needed, change the user.name to whatever you take from the response
              postWall.prepend(
              "<div class=\"msg\" user-id=\""+data.from+"\" ><strong>"+user.name+":</strong>"+data.message+"</div>"
              );
            }
        })
    });
    if(postWall.children().length == 0){
        postWall.prepend("<h1 style=\"color:red;\">No tienes ningun mensaje con esta persona</h1>")
    }
})

function isUserMatching (allUsers, userId) {
  let matched = false
  allUsers.map(user => {
    if (user.id == userId) {
      matched = user
      break
    }
  })
  return matched
}
```

Comment: Gracias ya lo entiendo!!!